# Having trouble to select an element while other is in :target

Tags: html, css, target

i'm just starting to learn how to use html5 and css3, and I came across with this problem:

Is there a way to select other element while other is on :taget with css?

Let me explain with an example:

```
Html:
<body>
<header>
<nav id="menu">
    <ul id="buttons">
       <li><a href="#">button</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">button</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>

<section id="one">
   <h2>title</h2>
   <p>text</p>
<section>
</body>
```

The idea is to put #menu on target and make #one, for example, change it's color.
I had read about "siblings selectors" (+ and ~ i think) is that a possible solution if both elements are sons of the body?

Sorry for my english, it's not my native lenguage. Thanks in advance!

Comment: apply class to the div will it help to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all validate your HTML code

1. there is no `</ul>` close tag.
2. `</a>` tag no need in `<li>` tag.

```
<body>
    <header>
    <nav id="menu">
        <ul id="buttons">
           <li>text</li>
           <li>text</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </header>
    
    <section id="one">
       <h2>title</h2>
       <p>text</p>
    <section>
</body>
```

How can use `:target`.

The **[:target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target)** CSS pseudo-class represents a unique element (the target element) with an id matching the URL's fragment.

```
/* Selects an element with an ID matching the current URL's fragment */
:target {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

For example, the following URL has a fragment (denoted by the # sign) that points to an element called section2:

```
http://www.example.com/index.html#section2
```

The following element would be selected by a `:target` selector when the current URL is equal to the above:

```
<section id="section2">Example</section>
```

**Working Demo**

```css
:target {
  color: #00cc00;
}
```

```html
<h3>Table of Contents</h3>
<ol>
 <li><a href="#p1">Jump to the first paragraph!</a></li>
 <li><a href="#p2">Jump to the second paragraph!</a></li>
 <li><a href="#nowhere">This link goes nowhere,
   because the target doesn't exist.</a></li>
</ol>

<h3>My Fun Article</h3>
<p id="p1">You can target <i>this paragraph</i> using a
  URL fragment. Click on the link above to try out!</p>
<p id="p2">This is <i>another paragraph</i>, also accessible
  from the links above. Isn't that delightful?</p>
```

Comment: You are right, thanks.

Comment: i updated answer :) are you want like this?